# selenium and event delegation

Tags: javascript, selenium

Does event delegation work with selenium? I'm listening for events on parent element and clicking on child elements do not fire it. Does anyone have experience with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

weird, if I run click twice works, same in Chrome and Firefox (OS X)